# Plot to include odds ratio for categorical variables with upper and lower limit 95%CI

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am working with data looking at the efficacy of farm management practices in relation to disease prevention.

Any help with how to create a plot in R showing the odds ratio with 95% for the variables. Codes for the independent variables are 0=not being practised at the farm, 1=practised. Orf.no.Orf.2012.2014 is the dependent variable with 0=no disease, 1= disease present. Thanks in advance

Here is the data sample plus some of the output:

```
Vet.Advice  Quarantine  Purchase.History Orf.no.Orf.2012.2014   
1           1           2                1  
0           0           0                1  
1           0           0                1  
0           0           0                1  
0           0           1                0  
1           0           0                1  
0           0           0                1  
0           1           0                1  
1           1           0                1  
0           0           1                1  
0           1           2                1  
0           0           0                1  


                             OR      2.5 %     97.5 %
(Intercept)               3.8251348 1.37283503 12.4437518
Footbath1                 1.7367032 0.91826113  3.3476932
Handwashing1              0.7927673 0.27360243  2.0484978
Handgels1                 1.4887936 0.58547658  4.3287735
Clean.Needles1            0.4719316 0.23958494  0.9120537
Vet.Vacc.Advice1          0.8666398 0.42396797  1.8096052
Disinfect.Trough1         0.7122465 0.36323418  1.3935948
Quarantine1               1.0648841 0.52899720  2.1936099
Quarantine2               0.2801078 0.06141656  1.1778524
Purchase.Disease.History1 0.5648420 0.26631744  1.1974933
Purchase.Disease.History2 0.4856445 0.13433826  1.7068997
```

Comment: What have you already tried yourself?

Comment: @Heroka, tried reading around with the few codes I came  across non seemed to be any closer to data example I have given above.

Comment: As this is not a code-writing service, I'm going to give you some hints and not write your code for you. First step is to get your outputdata in a dataframe, with a column indicating variables and one row per variable (you are already very close). Then you can plot this data using ggplot with variable as y, a geom_point for the OR and a geom_segment for the confidence interval.

Comment: thanks@Heroka tried your tip without luck. Still learning not so competent with coding and count come across links similar to my question/problem. Help even with basic code

Comment: Done. But as advice for the future: if you have trouble figuring this out even with the hints, you have a lot to learn in R. Do some tutorials. SO generally responds better to people who have made attempts (and shown why they were wrong) to solve their own problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go.

```
library(ggplot2)

#reading in data. You should be able
#to get this from your model by doing something like
#model_data <- exp(cbind(coef(model),confint(model)))
model_data <- read.table(text="
                                                     OR      2.5%     97.5%
(Intercept)               3.8251348 1.37283503 12.4437518
                         Footbath1                 1.7367032 0.91826113  3.3476932
                         Handwashing1              0.7927673 0.27360243  2.0484978
                         Handgels1                 1.4887936 0.58547658  4.3287735
                         Clean.Needles1            0.4719316 0.23958494  0.9120537
                         Vet.Vacc.Advice1          0.8666398 0.42396797  1.8096052
                         Disinfect.Trough1         0.7122465 0.36323418  1.3935948
                         Quarantine1               1.0648841 0.52899720  2.1936099
                         Quarantine2               0.2801078 0.06141656  1.1778524
                         Purchase.Disease.History1 0.5648420 0.26631744  1.1974933
                         Purchase.Disease.History2 0.4856445 0.13433826  1.7068997",
                         header=T)



#do some rearranging/renaming
colnames(model_data) <- c("OR","lower","upper")
model_data$variable <- rownames(model_data)

#plot without intercept (generally not reported)
p1 <- ggplot(model_data[-1,], aes(y=variable)) +
  geom_point(aes(x=OR)) + #plot OR
  geom_segment(aes(x=lower,xend=upper,yend=variable)) #plot confint

#add line for OR = 1
p1 <- p1 + geom_vline(xintercept=1) + theme_bw()
p1
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @Heroka, helpful indeed. Have noted your advice.

Comment: You're welcome. Not to beat my own drum, but please accept the answer if you're satisfied (checkmark under the vote button). Keeps others from spending time on the question.